# Import and embed plotly graphs from R to Google Sheets

Tags: r, google-sheets, plotly

I am currently working in R with some datasets coming from a GS spreadsheet. Having already dealt with them I've created some plotly graphs that I'd would like to import to the original GS spreadsheet.

Firstly I've been trying unsuccessfully with `gs_edit_cells` function, but it returns me the following error message:

```
    Error in catch_hopeless_input(input) : 
  Non-data-frame, list-like objects not suitable as input. Maybe pre-process it yourself?
```

How could I move on?